# Override theme function inside module, template_preprocess_field

Tags: 8

I'd like to implement [`template_preprocess_field`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_field/8.2.x) in a module for organizational purposes.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can also read this:
[Preprocessing and modifying attributes in a .theme file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/modifying-attributes-in-a-theme-file)

Answer (score 1):

Hook functions are named like so: MODULENAME_hook.

In your case that's:

```
function MODULENAME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {

}
```